# SASS - semantic lessons

Tags: css, html, sass, styling

Let's suppose we have code snippet like that:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav></nav>
    <header></header>
</div>
```

I think in HTML 5 era it's important to stylize code correctly. For instance - could you tell me which solution is better and why? And how can I learn that "semantic" of SASS?

First (div's layout is sustained):

```
.wrapper {
  nav { ... }
  header { ... }
}
```

The Second (all of elements are separate):

```
.wrapper {} 
nav {} 
header {}
```

*Of course - we're talking about situation when it isn't necessary to mark parent-children connections (all of these occur only once at site).

Comment: No, `close-voter`, this is not primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we're talking about SASS semantics here but the answer is that you probably want to let the nesting of your styles reflect the nesting of your markup.

So if your markup is nested as you say, then the nested styles are the correct way to do it. Additionally you may want to cautiously add more global styles in each scope but it's best to keep these to a minimum (as always with global information in software development).

Example:

```
body {
    .some-global-body-style;
    .nav {
        .some-global-nav-style;
        .subnav {}
    }

    .content {}
}
```